# Construct a game so that two random numbers appear and the user has to choose which one is bigger

Tags: python

AIM: Construct a game so that two random numbers appear and the user has to choose which one is bigger
This is what I have but I don't know how to make it so the code can realise if the  user has guessed the bigger number or not.

```
#Ask the user to input his/her name in which will be used in the
#opening comments about the game and how to play it

user_name=str(input("Please type in your name: "))
#print instructions
print('''Hello {}! Welcome!
This game is going to develop your number skills! 

So here is how to play:
Firstly, {}, we are going to give you two numbers.
Then you must choose which of these numbers you think is the biggest.
Type this number in and we will tell you if you are right.
Get enough right and you can progress TO THE NEXT LEVEL!!!''' .format(user_name, user_name))

#RUN MODULE TO CHECK IF THE TEXT IS BEING PRINTED AND THE USERS NAME IS BEING SHOWN IN SPACE OF THE {}

#level 1

#import a random number
import random

a1 = random.randint(1, 10)
a2 = random.randint(1, 10)

#Making sure the integers are not the same
while a1 == a2:
    a2 = random.randint(1, 10)

print('''
The two random values are {} and {}.
Which one do you think is bigger? ''' .format(a1, a2))

#RUN MODULE TO CHECK IF THE IF TWO NUMBERS ARE BEING PRODUCED AND ARE DIFFERENT, MAKING SURE THESE PRINT THROUGH THE THE PRINT STATEMENT.
```

Comment: Did you do all that and get stuck on this one part, or is that the professor's template?

Comment: Note: you can replace `'.... {} .... {} ....'.format(user_name, user_name)` with `'.... {name} .... {name} .....'.format(name=user_name)` avoiding repeated arguments to format

Comment: Python has an operator built-in specifically to tell which of two numbers is larger: [`>`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: well i was trying to make a variable so that like first_max = a1 > a2 and second_max = a2> a1 so that if the persons guess which is already set at user_num = int(input("What is the biggest number?") so if the first_max == user_num then they are correct but I dont think thats right haha

Comment: Yeah but the thing is i dont know how to make it so that the number they guess is correct if it is the bigger number or if the number they guess is incorrect because it is not the bigger one of the two numbers

Comment: I'm still uncertain as to whether A) the professor gave you a template requiring one small addition and you're asking us to do it for you, or B) you actually wrote the given code and you just need help with this last part.

Comment: I actually wrote the given code and just need help with the last part cause im stuck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is ask for the value of the biggest number, and compare it to the biggest number:

```
biggest = max(a1, a2)

user_num = int(input("What is the biggest number?"))

if user_num == biggest:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('Wrong! The biggest number is {}'.format(biggest))
```

Note the use of `int()` for converting the input to integer before testing for equality.

Comment: THANK YOU OMG IT WORKS YOU ARE MY HERO

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking your user is to choose one of two possible outcomes (bigger of smaller). You could say enter 1 if the first number is bigger than the second return if not.

```
k=raw_input("Enter 1 if first number bigger, else return: ")
```

the question is a choice between two outcomes.
You can alter your question slightly to generate a 1 or a zero using the random function then ask; Is a mystery number I have chosen a 1 or a zero enter 1 or 0

Answer (score -2):

```
# do this code 
a = raw_input()
# gets user input
if a1 > a2:
   if a == a1:
      print ('you got it right')
      break
# all the ifs check if it is right or wrong 
   if a != a1:
      print ('you got it wrong try again')
      a = raw_input() 
# then right this same code again but change if a1 > a2: do if a2 > a1: sorry if it does not work
```

Comment: there is something wrong with the break when i write another one changing the a1s to a2 like you said at the end it comes up with "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"